# C++ - How to check (at run-time) if Template Function Type matches Function Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

```
template <class T> 
class Links {
private:
  std::vector<Base*> linkVec;

public:
  Links<T>& operator += (Base*);
};

template <class T>
Links<T>& Links<T>::operator+=(Base* b) {

  //base is abstract, b will be passed in as derived type of b
  //I want to ONLY add base pointers to the SAME derived type to linkVec
  //How can I check at run-time (using down cast or dynamic cast?) if the 
  //derived type being passed is the same as the other derived types in the linkVec?
  //I would like to throw an exception if a different derived type is attempted to be added 
  //to linkVec

  linkVec.push_back(b);

  return *this;
}
```

The comments should sum up what I am trying to do here pretty well. But in short, I have a template class with a vector holding only pointers of the same derived type. I would like to throw an exception if a pointer of different derived type is added. I am not sure how to check the type at run-time and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Although you can use `dynamic_cast<>` for this, I'm not convinced that this is right thing to do. If you "have a template class with a vector holding only pointers of the same derived type", then declare the vector as containing pointers to `T`, with `T *` being the parameter to `push_back()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (maybe using ideone.com to host your code) so that we would be able to help you easily.

Comment: Why don't you implement `Links<T>& operator += (T &);` instead. 
For your problem, you can do `T * child = dynamic_cast<T>(b)`. If `child` is `NULL` your condition met

Comment: Why not to define your Links of derived type; as in `Links<Orange*> oLinks; Links<Bananas*> bLinks;`

Comment: Prefer compile time errors. I bet you would love the compiler to tell you that your code has a bug instead of your clients.